# Now Playing feature not displaying all tracks being played on Mac

Tags: macos, menu-bar, ventura, mediaplayer

I've been using the Now Playing feature on my Mac (Ventura 13.3.1) to control audio and video playback from multiple sources simultaneously.

However, I have noticed that it only displays one player for one app. This means that if I am listening to music in Safari and then start watching a video also in Safari, Now Playing switches to the last media object I interacted with. Also, it does not display the Previous and Next buttons for YouTube videos in Safari, instead replacing them with Rewind and Fast Forward buttons, for unknown reason.

*Buttons displayed in Now Playing for different applications, which are mutually exclusive, preventing the user from controlling playback and navigating between tracks with buttons simultaneously:*
[image: Safari.app: only rewind buttons]
[image: Music.app: normal buttons]

These, and especially one player per application limitation, are incredibly frustrating, as it makes it difficult to control playback and navigate between multiple tracks being played, let alone the volume control of individual tracks.

Does anyone know of any configuration change or third-party alternatives for playback control on Mac that could help me show all tracks being played?